# How can I add an unremovable prefix to an HTML input field?

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery, how can I add a default value of `http://` into an input field that can’t be removed, but that still allows you to type a URL after it?

Default: http://
Url: http://www.domain.name

Comment: How to add, or not how to add default value, *that* is the question...

Comment: if user didn't specify http://  to add if specified ignore it

Comment: Put it next to the input field, avoiding unnecessary complexity?

Comment: Why jQuery? Why not just a CSS background and padding?

Comment: if you're using bootstrap check out input-groups: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Answer (score 39):

this works well for me:

```
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
var oldvalue=$(this).val();
var field=this;
setTimeout(function () {
    if(field.value.indexOf('http://') !== 0) {
        $(field).val(oldvalue);
    } 
}, 1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J2BKU/

Comment: Keep in mind that while this works for all key events, it won't prevent user from dragging text into the form with mouse.

Comment: This doesn't work for dragging text into the form or selecting autocomplete string.

Comment: doesnt work if you paste a string using mouse right click.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem and solved it without using jquery, just simple CSS and HTML. The solution looks elegant and the user will immediately understand how it works.

Use the following code in your html:

```css
span.textbox {
     background-color: #FFF;
     color: #888;
     line-height:20px;
     height:20px;
     padding:3px;
     border:1px #888 solid;
     font-size:9pt;
}
    
span.textbox input {
      border: 0px;
     background-color: #FFF;
  }
```

```html
 (short title): 
    <span class="textbox"> 
        http://
        <input type="text" name="url" autofocus />
    </span>
```

The result will look like this (copied the result from my script, so it doesn't say http://):

[image]

Note that you only have to prepend the http:// in your script, but that will make it work perfectly.

Comment: I think this is the best way, if you want to avoid the prefix, while reading back from input.

Comment: This won't work if you need the prefix to be sent with a form, on the same field

Comment: @Stratboy indeed, but so far I haven't found a case where the script itself can't be adjusted. This is by far a more elegant way that doesn't confuse the user, and is supported almost everywhere.

Comment: @LucaReghellin Never make assumptions about user input. If the prefix is required it should be checked/added server-side anyway.

Comment: This won't scroll the prefix with the input text on overflow; the input will scroll separately so it's not completely seamless. But maybe that's not an issue.

Answer (score 19):

Check this **format util** and a prefix implementation for it:

- no glitching
- flexibility with regex
- any `input` event (*keyboard*, *mouse*, *drag-n-drop*, etc.)
- universal utility (extra formatters can be added)
- bug tested

```js
// Util function
function addFormatter (input, formatFn) {
  let oldValue = input.value;
  
  const handleInput = event => {
    const result = formatFn(input.value, oldValue, event);
    if (typeof result === 'string') {
      input.value = result;
    }
    
    oldValue = input.value;
  }

  handleInput();
  input.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
}

// Example implementation
// HOF returning regex prefix formatter
function regexPrefix (regex, prefix) {
  return (newValue, oldValue) => regex.test(newValue) ? newValue : (newValue ? oldValue : prefix);
}

// Apply formatter
const input = document.getElementById('link');
addFormatter(input, regexPrefix(/^https?:\/\//, 'http://'));
```

```css
input { padding: 0.5rem; font-size: 1rem; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="link" />
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: What if I wanted to add unremovable string after instead of before? .com, etc.

Comment: @Patrick1904 You can add a callback to `addFormatter` and set cursor position there:
[codepen link](https://codepen.io/doasync/pen/jObENpZ?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you @DoAsync

Comment: I am wondering: 

1. why do we need to pass event into the function `formatFn` ?
2. why do we need `oldValue = input.value;` at the end of function `handleInput` ?

Answer (score 18):

That's not possible. You can put a value in the input field, but it can be deleted.

You can put the text outside the input field, that will protect it from being deleted, but it won't be included in the value when the form is posted.

You can use absolute positioning to put the input field on top of the text, and use padding in the field so that you start typing after the text. Example:

CSS:

```
.UrlInput { position: relative; }
.UrlInput label { position: absolute; left: 3px; top: 3px; color: #999; }
.UrlInput input { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; padding-left:40px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="UrlInput">
  <label>http://</label>
  <input name="Url" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: my suggestion - since it's JS - allows you to actively TELL the user why they can't edit away http:// (tough the code in my answer was too lazy to bother). Yours just silently does not.

Comment: This won't work if you need the prefix to be sent with a form, on the same field.

Answer (score 8):

I’ve seen some web forms include this value outside of the field, e.g.

```
<label for="url">URL:</label> http:// <input id="url" type="text">
```

But if you’re dead set on enforcing the value via JavaScript (and bear in mind that users can turn JavaScript off), you could write a function that fires every time the user types in the field, and adds `http://` to the start of the field if it’s not there. E.g.

#### HTML:

```
<label for="url">URL:</label> <input id="url" type="text" value="http://">
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$('#url').keyup(function(){

    if( this.value.indexOf('http://') !== 0 ){ 
        // Add lots more code here so that this actually works in practice.    
        // E.g. if the user deletes only some of the “http://”, if the 
        // user types something before the “http://”, etc...
        this.value = 'http://' + this.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: The javascript way, in it's simple form, is downright horrible. Clearly, much more is needed to make that behave nicely (just try hitting backspace!) :). Here: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/Qw7QY/

Comment: @karim79: ooh yeah, that’s pretty bad. I sort of meant this as a starting point: you’d want to account for the situation where the user manages to enter some text before the `http://` as well.

Comment: fair enough. I did not mean for that to be an attack on your answer, either. It's just that I had already tried exactly that :) +1 for the first suggestion, anyway.

Comment: This is horribly broken for anything except the situation where the user deletes 100% of contents - it will result in strings like "http://ttp://whatever"

Comment: @karim79: oh no worries at all, I’m glad you pointed out the flaws: a lot of developers (myself included) will cut-and-paste code rather than read it, so non-working code should be very clearly marked.

Comment: The best js method would be to compute what the value is going to be and if it doesn't start with http:// return false in the event. I tried to make it, but it's too much work for something as insignificant. I only got backspace key working with no selection. http://jsbin.com/gigakoteja/1/edit?html,js,output
Even if you handle all key cases, you need to handle mouse events. I can easily bypass the accepted answer with mouse. I wish somebody make/made a plugin that handles this extensively.

Comment: In general you’re asking for trouble if you assume any specific input device/method on the web (`keyup` only applies to keyboard input, not on-screen keyboards, copy-paste, drag-drop, voice…). `input` is the “general” event designed to fire if the value of an `<input>` is changed in any way, but still doesn’t fire when modified with JS (e.g. by an assistive technology browser extension).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a HTML and CSS only option that, in my opinion, is cleaner than any of the other answers.

Give the input a `padding-left` to make space for the prefix. And position the a prefix element over that space.

```css
.prefix {
  position: relative;
  right: -3px;
  color: grey;
}

input.has-prefix {
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-left: -50px
}
```

```html
<span class="prefix">https://</span>
<input class="has-prefix" type="text">
```

Depending on how you want to align the `<input>` element, you can adjust the prefix's `right` position and the input's `margin-left` setting accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

All tested!

```js
$('#myUrl').keyup(function(e) {
  if (this.value.length < 7) {
    this.value = 'http://';
  } else if (this.value.indexOf('http://') !== 0) {
    this.value = 'http://' + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myUrl">URL:</label>
<input id="myUrl" type="text" value="http://">
```

Comment: Works beautifully!

Comment: Form.prototype.set_HttpPrefix = function (e) {
    if (e.data.$url.val().length < 7) {
        e.data.$url.val('http://')

    }    
    else if (e.data.$url.val().indexOf('http://') !== 0) {
        e.data.$url.val('http://' + String.fromCharCode(e.which)) 

  }
}

Answer (score 4):

This is just me playing around, but you can make a *fake* extension of the textbox. This example basically chops off the left border of the textbox and concatenates a fake textbox to the left.

**Works only in Chrome AFAICT**. You will have to add conditional stylesheets for each browser if you decide on this method.

http://jsfiddle.net/G9Bsc/1/

Comment: If you change the bottom-border to none on the span and the border-top-color to black. It looks pretty seemless in IE8 and FF4 as well. Still works in chrome too. jsfiddle.net/G9Bsc/10

Comment: Thanks. On Chrome 11 Dev, I get a missing bottom border, though. It's inset around the box.

Answer (score 3):

Pure CSS based solution we did make div wrapper and span input combination, please do refer follows

```css
.lable {
  background-color: #dedede;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
.snehainput {
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: #666666;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="lable">
  <span class="prefix">971</span>
  <input class="snehainput" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on 'http://' being the the default value, add the "value" attribute to the input tag:

```
<input id="url" type="text" value="http://">
```

Allow users to remove it if they wish, yet validate when the form is sent. ([jQuery's validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation))

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this in javascript, but I'm afraid it is more trouble than it's worth.

However, if you're sure the text won't change over time, you can use a **CSS background image** for the text input that is an image of your text 'http://'.  Then you can just add some padding-left until the user's input starts right next to the end of your image.

Answer (score 1):

Not so clean but it doesn't let users  remove your prefix

```
<input type="text" name="membership_num" value="0201" id="membership_num">  

//prefix
$(document).on('keyup','#membership_num',function(){
  var original = $('#membership_num').val().split('');
  original[0] = "0";
  original[1] = "2";
  original[2] = "0";
  original[3] = "1";
  $('#membership_num').val(original.join(''));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for the textbox, if user forgot to put http:// then it will add otherwise it won't.

```
if (this.value.length > 7) {
if(this.value.substring(0, 7)== "http://"  || this.value.substring(0, 
8)== "https://"){
    this.value = this.value;
    }
    else{
            this.value = "http://" + this.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Material UI Inputs can accept an input adornment prop for prefixes or suffixes:

https://material-ui.com/api/input-adornment/

```
<TextField
      label="With normal TextField"
      id="standard-start-adornment"
      className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">Kg</InputAdornment>,
      }}
    />
    <FormControl className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.withoutLabel, classes.textField)}>
      <Input
        id="standard-adornment-weight"
        value={values.weight}
        onChange={handleChange('weight')}
        endAdornment={<InputAdornment position="end">Kg</InputAdornment>}
        aria-describedby="standard-weight-helper-text"
        inputProps={{
          'aria-label': 'weight',
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about jQuery, but in plain JS, you can try to detect when the field changes and if the change somehow ruined the prefix, add it back (not 100% foolproof - if you want that, you have to just put the "http://" in a span outside the input field and add later programmatically):

```
<script>
function checkHttp(input) {
    // See if someone deleted 1 character from needed prefix.
    // We can't simply check if the string starts with the prefix
    // since the user may have backspaced out 1 character.
    input.value = input.value.replace(/^http:\/\//, "");
    input.value = input.value.replace(/^http:\//, "");            
    input.value = input.value.replace(/^http\/\//, "");            
    input.value = input.value.replace(/^htt:\/\//, "");            
    input.value = input.value.replace(/^htp:\/\//, "");            
    input.value = input.value.replace(/^ttp:\/\//, "");
    // This doesn't work if someone deletes - say via cut - >1 character.
    input.value = input.value.replace(/^/, "http://");
}
</script>
<input type='text' name='x' id='x' value='http://' onChange='checkHttp(this)'>
```

Please note that such a weird behavior is really confusing to the user without either explicit explanation beforehand, OR a pop-up (may be non-modal one) explaining that you fixed his mistake for him.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input").keyup(function(e) {
  var oldvalue = $(this).val();
  var field = this;
  if (field.value.indexOf('http://') === -1 &&
    field.value.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
    $(field).val('http://');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value='http://'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Guillaumesm's answer to Ecmascript 5:

```
Form.prototype.set_HttpPrefix = function (e) {
    if (e.data.$url.val().length < 7) {
        e.data.$url.val('http://')

    }    
    else if (e.data.$url.val().indexOf('http://') !== 0) {
        e.data.$url.val('http://' + String.fromCharCode(e.which)) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use input pattern

```
    <input
      placeholder="https://www.website.com"
      value={variable}                        //state variable
      onInput={(e) => handleInput(e)}
      pattern="(^h$)|(^ht$)|(^htt$)|(^http$)|(^https$)|(^https:$)|(^https:\/$)|(^https:\/\/.*)"
    />

    const handleInput = (e) => {
      setVariable(e.target.validity.valid ? e.target.value : variable);
    };
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32671088)