# jQuery input format for phone number prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make an input where the text would be: (+444), and I need to let the user insert those numbers, the (+) part is always there.

I searched whole google but didn't find a easy solution with jQuery or maybe even native Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an unremovable prefix to an HTML input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535963/how-can-i-add-an-unremovable-prefix-to-an-html-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/

https://square.github.io/field-kit/

https://catamphetamine.github.io/input-format/

are some that might do what you want. The term to search is likely input formatting/masking.