# Add leading symbol to input field

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to add leading and ending symbols or text to input field which cannot be removed?

I am trying to have a $ at the beginning and % at the end of two fields. Similar to the input fields on this website: https://www.nerdwallet.com/mortgages/mortgage-calculator

```
<input type="text" maxlength="12" name="purchasePrice" data-name="purchasePrice" placeholder="$200,000" required="">
<input type="text" maxlength="3" name="rate" data-name="rate" placeholder="2%" required="">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add an unremovable prefix to an HTML input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535963/how-can-i-add-an-unremovable-prefix-to-an-html-input-field)

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't even bother with javascript and just put a `$` in a `span` to the left of the `input`. Sure, it's not technically inside the input box, but it gets the point across.

Comment: @AmmarOker - I was looking for an answer that has the prefix inside the input instead of in a span.

Comment: @cann0nextr3me if you're willing to use jQuery, that's exactly what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871240/11877987) does. otherwise, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431760/11877987) for pure javascript.

Comment: @AmmarOker Its almost close. Only issue is that it lets the user type before the prefix which causes another prefix to be added.

Comment: well, then I agree with @Aplet123 on using a span, check out this pure CSS solution http://jsfiddle.net/ammar_oker/ey9ug3v4/12/